# how to give re.search() a line from a file

Tags: python, regex

I can't figure out how to give re.match() an individual line from a txt file.

For example:

```
file = open('foo.txt','r')
for line in file:
    if re.search('e', file):
        print line
```

Even though I know 'e' is in file, the re.match function does not evaluate to true. Why is this?

Comment: If you want the regex to match the whole file, you need to specify multiline mode. Add `re.MULTILINE` as a final parameter to `re.search`. However, I'm guessing @larsmans solution is actually what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
re.search('e', file)
```

should be

```
re.search('e', line)
             # ^^^^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Silly oversight on my part :)